# How does decode_entities() work?

Tags: 7

Let's say `$node->field_description[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']` contains `'We&#039;re in this together'`.

This code doesn't output what I expect.

```
$node = menu_get_object();
if (isset($node->field_description[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) {
  $text = strip_tags($node->field_description[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);
  $text = decode_entities($text);
}
```

instead of `'We're in this together'`, I get `'We&#039;re in this together'`.

The full hook implementation is the following.

```
function MY_MODULE_page_alter($page) {
  // Provide list description.
  $node = menu_get_object();
  if (isset($node->field_description[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) {
    $text = strip_tags($node->field_description[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);
    $text = decode_entities($text);
  }

  // Add metadata to describe site's content.
  $description = array(
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'name' => 'description',
      'content' => $text,
    ),
  );
  drupal_add_html_head($description, 'desciption');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `decode_entities` works as you expect.  It converts the HTML entity (`&#039;`) into a single quote and returns the decoded string.

However, that single quote will be expanded into an entity again at some point downstream, when the page is rendered.  This is what inserts (provided you spell "description" correct) the following into your page's `<head>`:

```
<meta name="description" content="We&#039;re in this together" />
```

I would not worry about this.  The above is a perfectly valid HTML meta-tag and will be interpreted correctly for SEO purposes, etc.

Comment: This is how I had it originally. I changed it back above, but still the same result?

Comment: I tested the contents of the function: html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') on codepad.viper-7.com and it worked fine. It's not my version of PHP either, which is 5.4. Caches cleared. Browser cache cleared. Hmm?

Comment: I'm using the code in an implementation of `hook_page_alter()`. maybe that is changing it back before rendering?

Comment: Debug: 'we\'re' is displayed in a message, and when I look at the source code in my Chrome browser the output is: We&#039;re.

Comment: Where are you seeing this manipulation by `drupal_add_html_head`? in `theme_html_tag`?

Comment: The expansion is not done by `drupal_add_html_head`. Note that the string as it appears in your page is not *rendered* by `drupal_add_html_head`, so a lot of things may happen to it after you call `drupal_add_html_head`.

Comment: Furthermore, realize that `decode_entities($text)` is, in Drupal 7 anyway, **just** a wrapper for returning `html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')` so check out http://us3.php.net/html_entity_decode for lots of further information...

Comment: @Jimajamma, I am well aware of that.  However, `decode_entities` has nothing whatsoever to do with the problem the OP thinks he has.

Comment: @GisleHannemyr, my comment was towards the OP, not your explanation, and was meant to further augment that it doesn't do anything special drupalwise.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I would need to look for a hook to alter this further down stream then.